# Rails 5.2: Issue with jquery-rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am developing Rails 5.2 application, and everything works fine under development mode. The main focus is the javascript manifest.

`app/assets/javacripts/application.js`

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And the jquery-rails is already included: `gem 'jquery-rails'`

The jquery from manifest works fine during development, but when I deploy to production with `RAILS_ENV=production`, the debug console throws me an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: wt.each is not a function
    at application-f391c00e32925e724aeeeafb89a9def5fe54c457b371cab55c13d97dc54382cd.js:formatted:789
    at application-f391c00e32925e724aeeeafb89a9def5fe54c457b371cab55c13d97dc54382cd.js:formatted:9
    at application-f391c00e32925e724aeeeafb89a9def5fe54c457b371cab55c13d97dc54382cd.js:formatted:10
```

Sometimes it is given as `xt`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: xt.each is not a function
    at application-01f2edddc7a85d2c9e116d47f0c8eb10e41b5d6a06d8832122e5545bb2d1068f.js:formatted:1340
    at application-01f2edddc7a85d2c9e116d47f0c8eb10e41b5d6a06d8832122e5545bb2d1068f.js:formatted:559
    at application-01f2edddc7a85d2c9e116d47f0c8eb10e41b5d6a06d8832122e5545bb2d1068f.js:formatted:560
```

and the error leads to this line of code:

```
wt.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error Symbol".split(" "), function(t, e) {
    ht["[object " + e + "]"] = e.toLowerCase()
});
```

But when I checked the original Jquery code, it's not `wt` (or sometimes `xt`), but `w`:

```
w.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error Symbol".split(" ") 
// The code goes on
```

I suspect that Rails did some changing behind the scene, and how can I fix this?

Here are some things that I have tried:

1. Use assets from `public` folder the standard way: [Works Fine]
2. Use other version of jquery, i.e., `jquery`, `jquery2`, `jquery3`: [Not Working]

Currently I am using method `1` above as current workaround, but my project is not organized such way.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please try again after changing the variable name `w` to any proper name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having frustrations for days, I found out the main issue.

`uglifier`

Removing/commenting out uglifier from my production's initializer seems to work. Although it is not hygienic to have uncompressed assets, it still works.

It seems `Uglifier` did some mangling behind the scene (which changes the variable name), along with compression. Setting the option of `mangle: false` did not work out for me, even with `harmony: true` for unknown reason.

Check out the documentation to see if there's any option that might works out for your specific need.

https://github.com/lautis/uglifier

You can configure uglifier in `app/assets/production.rb` with the following:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true, mangle: false)
```

It didn't work for me, thus I simply commented out that particular line, until I'm able to figure out how to work around it.

```
# Didn't work, commenting out
#
# config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true, mangle: false)
```